# jQuery add different classes per if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm struggling to get jQuery to assign the correct class per data value.
If the td .FuelInjectorQty has a value less than 3, it should add the class .FiJlowQty to the parent tr.FuelInjectorRow
If the td .FuelInjectorQty is greater than or equal to 3, it should add the class .FiJhiQty to the parent tr.FuelInjectorRow

```
if ($('.FuelInjectorQty').data('value') < 3) {
  $('.FuelInjectorRow').addClass("FiJlowQty");
} else if ($('.FuelInjectorQty').data('value') >= 3) {
  $('.FuelInjectorRow').addClass("FiJhiQty");
}
```

I have it half working, where it applies one or the other, but will not do it again for the second occurrence. Feel like I need a loop or something, so I was trying out each() but couldn't make it work.

```
   $('.FuelInjectorRow').each(function(i) {
    if ($('.FuelInjectorQty').data('value') < 3) {
      $('.FuelInjectorRow').addClass("FiJlowQty");
    } else if ($('.FuelInjectorQty').data('value') >= 3) {
      $('.FuelInjectorRow').addClass("FiJhiQty");
    }
  });
```

See Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/bpo29/tmbp67nL/85/

Thank you for any pointers & help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `$(this)` to correctly select the element you r are dealing with.

https://jsfiddle.net/tmbp67nL/86/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
  $('.FuelInjectorRow').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).find('.FuelInjectorQty').data('value') < 3) {
      $(this).addClass("FiJlowQty");
    } else if ($(this).find('.FuelInjectorQty').data('value') >= 3) {
      $(this).addClass("FiJhiQty");
    }
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to target the `tr` you want to add a class to and then use `.addClass( function )` where the function return the appropriate class to add to the `tr` element.

```
$('.FuelInjectorRow').addClass( function() {
    return +$(this).find('.FuelInjectorQty').data('value') < 3 ? 'FiJlowQty' : 'FiJhiQty';
} );
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.FuelInjectorRow').addClass( function() {
        return +$(this).find('.FuelInjectorQty').data('value') < 3 ? 'FiJlowQty' : 'FiJhiQty';
    } );
});
```

```css
/*  Uploads Grid */

#UploadGrid {
  font-size: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 238px;
  float: left;
}

#UploadGrid table {
  margin: 0px;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#UploadGrid td {
  padding: 0;
  height: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

td.DocUploadTitle {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: black !important;
  color: white;
  height: 35px !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-indent: 2em;
  padding-top: 4px !important;
}

.DocUploadGridHeader {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 30px;
}

.DNCol {
  width: 70px
}

.DDCol {
  width: 65px
}

.PNCol {
  width: 78px
}

.QCol {
  width: 25px
}

#UploadGrid table td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #e0e0e0
}

/*
.FuelInjectorRow td {background: #f1b5b5 !important} 
*/

.FiJlowQty td {
  background: #f1b5b5 !important
}


.FiJhiQty td {
  background: #8fe28f !important
}

.FiJlowNote {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 14px;
  background-color: #f1b5b5;
}

.FiJhiNote {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 14px;
  background-color: #8fe28f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="UploadGrid">
  <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="DocUploadTitle">Your Uploaded Documents</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="DocUploadGridHeader">
        <td class="DNCol">Document
          <br>Number</td>
        <td class="DDCol">Document
          <br>Date</td>
        <td class="PNCol">Part
          <br>Number</td>
        <td class="QCol">Qty.</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="NotFuelInjector">
        <td>1111</td>
        <td>1/1/2017</td>
        <td class="">120181C92R</td>
        <td class="" data-value="5">5</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="FuelInjectorRow">
        <td>Should Be Red</td>
        <td>3/1/2017</td>
        <td class="FuelInjectorCell">288865A1R</td>
        <td class="FuelInjectorQty" data-value="2">2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="NotFuelInjector">
        <td>21313</td>
        <td>4/1/2017</td>
        <td class="">1315328C4R</td>
        <td class="" data-value="1">1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="NotFuelInjector">
        <td>213212</td>
        <td>5/1/2017</td>
        <td class="">1315328C4R</td>
        <td class="" data-value="1">1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="FuelInjectorRow">
        <td>Shouldnt Be Red</td>
        <td>6/14/2017</td>
        <td class="FuelInjectorCell">JR908507</td>
        <td class="FuelInjectorQty" data-value="4">4</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class='FiJlowNote'>The red highlighted row(s) are Fuel Injectors that progress will not be awarded for.
    <br> You must install Fuel Injectors in quantities of 3 or more to recieve progress.</div>

  <div class='FiJhiNote'>The green highlighted row(s) are Fuel Injectors that progress WILL be awarded for.
    <br> You have installed Fuel Injectors in quantities of 3 or more.</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to access the `.FuelInjectorQty` of the current `.FuelInjectorRow` using `find`:

```
$('.FuelInjectorRow').each(function(i) {
    var qte = $(this).find('.FuelInjectorQty').data('value');

    if (qte < 3) {
        $(this).addClass("FiJlowQty");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("FiJhiQty");
    }
});
```

**Note:** `$(this)` will be equivalent to the current `.FuelInjectorRow`, if you don't use it and use `$('.FuelInjectorRow')` then the classes will be appended to all the `.FuelInjectorRow` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Looping with `each()` should be the way to go, but you need to use the context of each iteration. Right now you're just reselecting every element on the page in every iteration

The context is `this` so here's what you need to do:

```
$('.FuelInjectorRow').each(function() {
  var $row = $(this);
  var value = $row.find('.FuelInjectorQty').data('value');

  if (value < 3) {
    $row.addClass("FiJlowQty");
  } else if (value >= 3) {
    $row.addClass("FiJhiQty");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the loop, you need to use the context of the loop, `this`:

```
$('.FuelInjectorRow').each(function(i) {
  var row = $(this);
  var qty = row.find('.FuelInjectorQty').data('value');
  if (qty < 3) 
     row.addClass("FiJlowQty");
  else
    row.addClass("FiJhiQty"); 
});
```